# Android app shall wait for specific amount of bytes from BLE source

Tags: android, string, bluetooth-lowenergy

in my app i receive a string via BLE. It is a protocol from a sensor, so it has a start and end byte, several identification bytes and data bytes. After i received a full protocol string i need to cut the string into pieces. The start/end flag is 0xA8.

If data is found, the following method empties the buffer and calls "onUiReceiveData(final String dataReceived)" for further string cutting operation:

```
public void onVspReceiveData(BluetoothGatt gatt,
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch)
{
    mRxBuffer.write(ch.getStringValue(0));

    while (mRxBuffer.read(mRxDest) != 0)
    {
        /*
         * found data
         */
        String rxBufferDataRead = mRxDest.toString();
        mRxDest.delete(0, mRxDest.length());
        mSerialManagerUiCallback.onUiReceiveData(rxBufferDataRead);
    }
}
```

mRxBuffer is a FifoQueue
mRxDest is a StringBuilder

My problem is that the app is crashing everytime it is receiving data via BLE. The reason lies in the app handing over just a few bytes of the data to "onUiReceiveData(...)" and not the whole string. So the further methods cut the string, but it becomes too soon too short and the app crashes.

So how do i wait for a specific amount of data, or especially to the point that i have received a full protocol from "0xA8" as start and another "0xA8" as end flag?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `ch.getStringValue(0)` doing? Shouldn't the entire string be in the BLE packet (does it all fit)? Or is it sending the string in chunks?

Comment: getStringValue gives its value with offset 0 to the bluetooth gatt characteristic ch. this value is written into the mRxBuffer afterwards.

Seems like the BLE module is sending the string in chunks.

I just can't figure out how i wait for a specific amount of data and then proceed with further operations.

Comment: If the data string is a fixed length then you could simply check the length before passing it onto `onUiReceiveData`. If it's not then you could set a Boolean flag for the start of a message (e.g. `bMsgStart`)  and then another for the end (e.g. `bMsgEnd`), so you'll know when you're in a message and waiting for the end byte. Then when you receive the data you just don't pass it to `onUiReceiveData` until you have a complete message. The flags would need to be global, and the data buffer (so you don't lose what you've already received and can add to it each time `onVspReceiveData` is called).